# Rails 5 with Active Storage causing minimagick::invalid error with message improper image header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minimagick, rails-activestorage

After upgrading to rails 5 with Active Storage, I'm having this error for each upload.

```
Failure/Error: self.image.variant(resize: large_size).processed
 MiniMagick::Invalid:
   `identify /var/folders/9f/llmvc73n031_s_hn2fqg1czh0000gn/T/mini_magick20180706-88409-k0z76z.png` failed with error:
   identify: improper image header `/var/folders/9f/llmvc73n031_s_hn2fqg1czh0000gn/T/mini_magick20180706-88409-k0z76z.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/4229
```

This is my gemfile.

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'

gem 'execjs' 
gem 'therubyracer'

#gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
```

Does anyone experience this?

Comment: This occured to me. The docs says you can preview a PDF file. I installed what the docs indicate and also have installed Image Magick but the `preview` method have problems for non-image files.

when I use it on an image, everything goes fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was something else. I was trying to solve this [Rails 5 ActiveStorage How to wait for all threads to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236616/rails-5-activestorage-how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish/51241530#51241530). And I thought it's something related to ActiveStorage. But actually the answer in the other page is related to the way I code.